# Run command in script and check return value

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I am trying to run the `diff` command on two folders, check the return value and then output a message.

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

result='diff dir1 dir2'

if result == 0
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

But I am getting `result: command not found`

How should I execute the command and return the value, to be compared in the `IF`?

Comment: I'm no bash expert, but try `${result}`.

Comment: You need to use $result instead of result in the if statement.

Comment: Also, use back-tics ` instead of single quotes, and $? to check the return value of the command. $? is a special variable that hold the exit code of the last command executed.

Comment: @Xilpex No, that won't work. See the two answers for working methods.

Comment: @Ankush No, `$result == 0` won't work. See the two answers for working methods. As well, use the new command substitution syntax `$()` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 4):

Quite some problems here. This is an example, but you should do more research in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash

result="$(diff dir1 dir2)"
ret=$?
if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "ERROR"
fi
exit $ret
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need both result and ret=$?

Comment: @user997112 You don't, but that's how Bayou interpreted the question. It looks like you're trying to also capture the output of the `diff` command. I interpreted it the other way - see my answer.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I want the return code of `diff` to be stored in `result`, so I can query it in the if statement (I know I can do it your way, but my diff command has a few flags too)

Comment: @user997112 You don't need to store the return code, that's what I'm trying to say in my answer.

Comment: @user997112 Also to be clear, "output" and "return code" are not the same thing.

Comment: @wjandrea I want the return code, not the output. To clarify, I want to store the return code to a variable because I didn't want to put a long command in an IF statement

Comment: The return value is not returned by the program this way. You always should use `$?` for that.

Comment: @user997112 FWIW you can avoid long command lines by putting the arguments in an array

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to check it directly:

```
#!/bin/bash

if diff dir1 dir2; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

If you don't want `diff` to print anything, use the `-q` flag.

Answer (score 0):

please use `${result}` instead.
Also, note the backticks on the actual command

```
#!/bin/bash

result=`diff dir1 dir2`

if [[ -z ${result} ]]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

Comment: Use the new command substitution syntax `$()` instead of backticks.

Comment: It says to use ${result} but result is not queried in the IF statement?

Comment: `$?` gives the status of the last executed command, in this case.

`
diff dir1 dir2
`

As such, you can completely avoid using result

Comment: @foolstuckdev How would I use `result` explicitly? (I don't like implicit programming)

Comment: @user997112 `diff` provides a comparison between operands, so if you want your result as OK in case there is no change, use the -z flag. Please see the updated solution post

Comment: Thank you for answering. As someone that rarely writes bash, can you see why I'm confused there's no comparison with 0/1?